# 「yum remove php*」と「yum remove php php-*」の違い

Tags: php, centos, yum

`yum remove php*` と `yum remove php php-*` では何が異なりますか？
使い分け方等があれば知りたいです。

環境
CentOS7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[「# yum remove php*」を実行したら、引数に一致しません: php72_20221219.ini　削除対象とマークされたパッケージはありません。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/92890/)
で書いた通り shell glob に展開されうるのでどちらも不適です。

> PHPをアップデートするために既存PHPを削除する場合には、

もし仮に `phph-hogehote-version.arch.rpm` なんてものが存在するとして、そっちは削除対象にしたくないのであれば `yum remove 'php-*'` のほうが適切です（これだと `phph` にはヒットしない）削除したいのであれば `yum remove 'php*'` で十分。

Answer (score 1):

単純に「パッケージ名にどうマッチさせるかどうか」の違いだけです。
`yum remove` だけでなく、`yum list` や `yum search` も活用してください。

CentOS の標準リポジトリを対象にすると、`php*` は以下のパッケージにマッチします。

https://pkgs.org/search/?q=php

```
php-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

`php-*` は以下のようなパッケージにマッチします。

```
php-bcmath-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64.rpm
php-cli-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64.rpm
php-common-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64.rpm
php-dba-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64.rpm
php-devel-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64.rpm
php-embedded-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64.rpm
php-enchant-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64.rpm
php-fpm-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64.rpm
php-gd-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: PHPをアップデートするために既存PHPを削除する場合には、どちらのコマンドがより適切ですか？