# 「# yum remove php*」を実行したら、引数に一致しません: php72_20221219.ini　削除対象とマークされたパッケージはありません。

Tags: centos, yum

/etc/php.ini を /home/hoge/backup へコピーしました。
その際、ファイル名を php72_20221219.ini に変更しました。

その後、/home/hoge/backup へ移動して `yum remove php*` を実行したら以下のメッセージが表示されました。

```
 読み込んだプラグイン:fastestmirror, langpacks
 引数に一致しません: php72_20221219.ini
 削除対象とマークされたパッケージはありません。
```

なぜですか？　どういう意味ですか？
このコマンドは実行する場所によって、結果が異なるのですか？

Comment: まずは実際にインストールされているパッケージ名を確認しましょう。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

コマンドラインから手入力した `*` は shell glob となるので glob 規則で合致するファイル名ディレクトリ名があればそれに展開されます。あなたのその `/home/hoge/backup` ディレクトリには `php72_20221912.ini` というファイルがあるわけなので

```
# cd /home/hoge/backup
# echo php*
php72_20221912.ini
#
```

と全く同じことが `yum remove` でも発生するので `yum remove php*` は `yum remove php72_20221912.ini` と展開されることになり、質問文の通りの結果が得られることでしょう。

glob に展開されないよう `yum remove 'php*'` と入力すると動作は変わるはずです（それがあなたの期待した動作であるかはまた話が別）

Comment: shell "glob"といって通じる人は最近少ないと思います。一般的にはシェルの展開機能の１つ、「パス名展開」により、コマンド文字列の「php*」が「php72_20221912.ini」に置き換えられて解釈されるため、というべきですね。またお使いのシェルのマニュアルページを調べる旨付け加えるべきです(事前にシェルを聞いたほうがいいけど)。

Comment: globによるパス名展開とは、例えば「yum remove hoge*」と入力した場合、カレントディレクトリ以下に「hoge.txt」があったなら「yum remove hoge.txt」へ置き換わったコマンドが実行される、ということですか？

Comment: 「以下」はいらなくて、カレントディレクトリに `hoge.txt` があったら `yum remove hoge.txt` に展開された後に実行されるわけです。（ `foo/bar/hoge.txt` があっても置換されない、の意味）

Comment: なるほど、良く分かりました